# Combine if statements

Tags: java

So i have these if statements and I have 2 questions. First is there a way to combine these statement to make 1 big if condition. Also, I was wondering if there was a way to make it so if the condition is true then automatically end the method. I don't actually want to say "no freight train" I want to end the method if the if statement are true.

```
public void rule4(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled){
    if (dierolled.contains(1)){
        System.out.println("no freight train");
    }
    if (dierolled.contains(3)){
        System.out.println("no freight train");
    }
    if (dierolled.contains(10)){
        System.out.println("no freight train");
    }
```

}

Comment: Use `&&, ||` for combining if statements and `return` to end the method.

Comment: Could also return if any of these conditions are false, otherwise print whatever you want.

Comment: @MuratK. ohhhhh alright. so like dierolled.contains(1&&3&&10)?

Comment: actually, to mimic the original behavior, "||" is closer than "&&", but as written in OP, it will repeat the output several times because they weren't in "else" blocks

Comment: @S.Vono That unfortunately does not work in Java syntax. You have to write every if statement.

Comment: You can also refactor it to another function with one parameter that is the condition and the other a successful callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine if statements, try this:

```
if (dierolled.contains(1) || dierolled.contains(3) || dierolled.contains(10)) {
    System.out.println("no freight train");
}
```

The above is essentially saying this: 
If dierolled contains 1 **OR** dierolled contains 3 **OR** dierolled contains 10 then print "no freight train"

```
if (dierolled.contains(1) && dierolled.contains(3) && dierolled.contains(10)) {
        System.out.println("no freight train");
    }
```

The above is essentially saying this: 
If dierolled contains 1 **AND** dierolled contains 3 **AND** dierolled contains 10 then print "no freight train"

To end the method, simply add `return;`

Comment: This now makes sense! Thanks to you and everyone for the help!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use the element stream() from your `dierolled` List and check if any terms match. If so, `return;` - otherwise do what you want to do when there is "a freight train". Like,

```
public void rule4(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled) {
    if (dierolled.stream().anyMatch(x -> x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 10)) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("freight train");
}
```

Comment: Should be the other way around

Comment: I see you changed the print statement..

Comment: @MuratK. OP says *I don't actually want to say "no freight train" I want to end the method if the if statement are true.*; which I **think** means if the `List` contains a one, a three, or a ten then immediately return. Otherwise, OP hasn't actually said what they want to happen - but I have indicated that condition as being "freight train". I didn't change anything. I rolledback your edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void rule4(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled){
    if (dierolled.contains(1) || dierolled.contains(3) || dierolled.contains(10)) 
    return;
}
```

or return the boolean value if you need to use it somewhere:

```
public boolean rule4(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled){
    return dierolled.contains(1) || dierolled.contains(3) || dierolled.contains(10) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use **one if statement with the 3 conditions** and a `return` statement at the end to quit the method:

```
public void rule4(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled){
    if (dierolled.contains(1) || dierolled.contains(3) || dierolled.contains(10)){
        System.out.println("no freight train");
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void rule4(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled){
    if (dierolled.contains(1) 
            || dierolled.contains(3)
            || dierolled.contains(10)
       )
    {
        return;
    }
    /* Other code can go here */
 }
```

Should work. You might also want to factor out the 'IF' conditions into their own method for readability, such as `private boolean noFreightTrain(List<Integer> dieRolled)`